# Use WCF web service from client and server

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, wcf, web-services

I'm trying to make use of web services in an ASP.NET application I'm developing; currently I have a service running that I call form the client side to run AJAX queries against my database as textboxes are updated. This all works a treat. I am using the ASP.NET ScriptManager not jQuery ajax or any other third party tools.

I also need to make use of the logic in the web service elsewhere in the application - specifically if the page that uses it from the client gets posted back to the server (if a drop-down is changed) a lot of the calculated values need to be changed. It seems silly to duplicate the code in code-behind - is there a way I can access the existing service to do the calculations?

I've had a look at some other questions, but they talk a lot about SOAP, REST, Endpoints and Bindings, and I really don't understand a word of it! Some general advice or a pointer in the right direction would be great.

Comment: can you confirm what you mean by 'web services' you are using in the asp.net app? Are they asmx or wcf service you are hitting? also are the service, asp.net app and database all on the same box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution might be to factor out the pertinent code in your web service to a class library. Then you can reference this new class library from your web server and call the methods during the post-back.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take out the logic of your web method to another function in another class, then reuse that function in both your web method and your code-behind.